# Visual error in grid / Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

In this example, hide all series and after that, show the last serie (Serie3): the grid show bad.

http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoherlo/4bEuL/5/

But if I change the height of div container:
    `<div id="graf" style="min-width: 400px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>`
by
    `<div id="graf" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>`

then works fine!!

Any suggestion?

Comment: suggestions on what? And always avoid inline CSS.

Comment: I delete the css inline: http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoherlo/4bEuL/6/

Tips/suggestions for fixing grid look bad.

Comment: I can make it go wrong with height 400 as well. Looks like a highcharts bug.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug with redrawing the chart when the left yaxis no longer has any numbers ploted, which changes its width. You can work around this by setting a min and max value which forces it to show axis labels even if there are no series showing for that axis

```
yAxis: [{
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        min: 0,
        max:3100,
    }, {
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, so I've reported to our devs here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1667